# Deep learning model training troubleshooting : Loss and accuracy are not improving

Tags: python, performance, deep-learning, pytorch, loss

I replicated a deep learning model from a **research paper**, I replicated the same dataset, model (got the model from their github repository) and hyperparameters stated in the paper, they got an accuracy of 0.8 but when I trained the model, loss and accuracy remained the same across epochs :

- **before training :** 'val_loss': 1.065879225730896, 'val_acc': 0.0
- **epoch 1 :** 'val_loss': 0.5320051908493042, 'val_acc':
  0.3277043104171753
- **epoch 2 :** 'val_loss': 0.5320051908493042, 'val_acc':
  0.3211199939250946
- **epoch 3 :** 'val_loss': 0.5320051908493042, 'val_acc':
  0.3211086094379425
- **epoch 4 :** 'val_loss': 0.5320051908493042, 'val_acc':
  0.32110264897346497
- **epoch 5 :** 'val_loss': 0.5320051908493042, 'val_acc':
  0.32110220193862915
- **epoch 6 :** 'val_loss': 0.5320051908493042, 'val_acc':
  0.32110220193862915
- **epoch 7 :** 'val_loss': 0.5320051908493042, 'val_acc':
  0.32110220193862915
- **epoch 8 :** 'val_loss': 0.5320051908493042, 'val_acc':
  0.32110220193862915
- **epoch 9 :** 'val_loss': 0.5320051908493042, 'val_acc':
  0.32110220193862915
- **epoch 10 :** 'val_loss': 0.5320051908493042, 'val_acc':
  0.32110220193862915

I tried the **He initialization** method, the accuracy improved in the 1st epoch but dropped again to the same value :

- **before training :** 'val_loss': 0.8653618693351746, 'val_acc':
  0.004853446967899799
- **epoch 1 :** 'val_loss': 0.5325430035591125, 'val_acc':
  **0.6566311120986938**
- **epoch 2 :** 'val_loss': 0.5325430035591125, 'val_acc':
  0.3214294910430908
- **epoch 3 :** 'val_loss': 0.5325430035591125, 'val_acc':
  0.3214150369167328
- **epoch 4 :** 'val_loss': 0.5325430035591125, 'val_acc':
  0.32141244411468506
- **epoch 5 :** 'val_loss': 0.5325430035591125, 'val_acc':
  0.32141217589378357

Here is the code I used to train the model  :

```
L = 32
W = np.asarray([11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,
                21, 21, 21, 21, 41, 41, 41, 41])
AR = np.asarray([1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4,
                 10, 10, 10, 10, 25, 25, 25, 25])


class ResBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, L, W, AR, pad=True):
        super(ResBlock, self).__init__()
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(L)
        s = 1
        if pad:
            padding = int(1 / 2 * (1 - L + AR * (W - 1) - s + L * s))
        else:
            padding = 0
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(L, L, W, dilation=AR, padding=padding)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(L)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(L, L, W, dilation=AR, padding=padding)

        # Initialize convolutional layers with He initialization
        init.kaiming_uniform_(self.conv1.weight, mode='fan_in', nonlinearity='relu')
        init.kaiming_uniform_(self.conv2.weight, mode='fan_in', nonlinearity='relu')
        # Initialize batch normalization layers with default initialization
        self.bn1.weight.data.fill_(1)
        self.bn1.bias.data.zero_()
        self.bn2.weight.data.fill_(1)
        self.bn2.bias.data.zero_()

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.bn1(x)
        out = torch.relu(out)
        out = self.conv1(out)
        out = self.bn2(out)
        out = torch.relu(out)
        out = self.conv2(out)
        out = out + x
        return out

class Pangolin(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, L, W, AR):
        super(Pangolin, self).__init__()
        self.n_chans = L
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(4, L, 1)
        self.skip = nn.Conv1d(L, L, 1)
        self.resblocks, self.convs = nn.ModuleList(), nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(len(W)):
            self.resblocks.append(ResBlock(L, W[i], AR[i]))
            if (((i + 1) % 4 == 0) or ((i + 1) == len(W))):
                self.convs.append(nn.Conv1d(L, L, 1))
        self.conv_last1 = nn.Conv1d(L, 3, 1)
        init.kaiming_uniform_(self.conv1.weight, mode='fan_in', nonlinearity='relu')
        init.kaiming_uniform_(self.skip.weight, mode='fan_in', nonlinearity='relu')
        init.kaiming_uniform_(self.conv_last1.weight, mode='fan_in', nonlinearity='relu')

    def forward(self, x):
        conv = self.conv1(x)
        skip = self.skip(conv)
        j = 0
        for i in range(len(W)):
            conv = self.resblocks[i](conv)
            if (((i + 1) % 4 == 0) or ((i + 1) == len(W))):
                dense = self.convs[j](conv)
                j += 1
                skip = skip + dense
        CL = 2 * np.sum(AR * (W - 1))
        skip = F.pad(skip, (-CL // 2, -CL // 2))
        out = F.softmax(self.conv_last1(skip), dim=1)
        return out

    def training_step(self, batch):
        inputs, labels = batch
        out = self.forward(inputs)
        criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        loss = criterion(out,labels)
        return loss


    def validation_step(self, batch):
        inputs, labels = batch
        with torch.no_grad () :
            out = self.forward(inputs)
            criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
            loss = criterion(out, labels)
            accuracy = metrics(out,labels)
        return {'val_loss': loss.detach(), 'val_acc': accuracy}

    def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs):
        batch_losses = [x['val_loss'] for x in outputs]
        epoch_loss = torch.stack(batch_losses).mean()
        batch_accs = [x['val_acc'] for x in outputs]
        epoch_acc = torch.stack(batch_accs).mean()
        return {'val_loss': epoch_loss.item(), 'val_acc': epoch_acc.item()}


    def epoch_end(self, epoch, result):
        print('Epoch [{}], val_loss: {:.4f}, val_acc:{:.4f}'.format(epoch, result['val_loss'], result['val_acc']))


def evaluate(model, val_loader):
    outputs = [model.validation_step(batch) for batch in val_loader]
    return model.validation_epoch_end(outputs)

def fit(epochs, lr, model, train_loader, val_loader, opt_fun=torch.optim.AdamW):
    history = []
    optimizer = opt_fun(model.parameters(), lr)
    scheduler = StepLR(optimizer, step_size=1, gamma=0.5, verbose=True)

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        model.train()
        for b, batch in enumerate(train_loader):
            loss = model.training_step(batch)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad()            
        if epoch >= 6 :
            scheduler.step()
        model.eval()
        result = evaluate(model, val_loader)
        model.epoch_end(epoch, result)
        history.append(result)        
        print(result)
    return history

def metrics(out, labels) :
    accuracy = torch.tensor(torch.sum(out == labels).item() / out.numel())
    return accuracy

def get_default_device():
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        return torch.device('cuda')
    else :
        return torch.device('cpu')

def to_device(data, device):
    if isinstance(data, (list, tuple)):
        return [to_device(x, device) for x in data]
    return data.to(device, non_blocking=True)

class DeviceDataLoader():
    def __init__(self, dl, device):
        self.dl = dl
        self.device = device
    def __iter__(self):
        for b in self.dl :
            yield to_device(b, self.device)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dl)

class H5Dataset(data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, path):
        super(H5Dataset, self).__init__()
        self.path = path
        self.file = h5py.File(path, 'r')
        self.keys = list(self.file['LabelsGTF2/Training'].keys())

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        key = self.keys[index]
        key2 = key.replace('L', 'I')
        key2 = '/Training/' + key2
        key = 'LabelsGTF2/Training/' + key
        inputs = np.array(self.file[key2])
        inputs = torch.tensor(inputs)
        labels = self.file[key]
        labels = np.array(labels)
        labels = torch.tensor(labels)
        labels = labels[:,5001:10001]

        return inputs, labels.float()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.keys)


dataset = H5Dataset('E:\\Dataset\\human\\Dataset.h5')
batch_size= 12
train_ratio = 0.9
train_size = int(len(dataset) * train_ratio)
val_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train_dataset, val_dataset = data.random_split(dataset, [train_size, val_size])
train_loader = data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
val_loader = data.DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size)
device = get_default_device()
train_loader = DeviceDataLoader(train_loader, device)
val_loader = DeviceDataLoader (val_loader, device)
model = Pangolin(L, W, AR)
to_device(model, device)
history = []
history += fit(10, 0.001, model, train_loader, val_loader)
```

Comment: Consider posting a minimal reproducible example if it's possible, it will make your program much easier to debug. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: take a look at `train_loss`, as it often gives good hints on what is wrong (for example small values when overfitting)